# getting "undefined" when rewriting _.find function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

I am trying to rewrite the underscore _.find() for practice and am getting undifined when running it. Heres the code:

```
// _.find(list, predicate, context);

var findIt = function(list, predicate) {
    for (var i = 0; i < i.length; i++) {
        if (predicate(list[i]) == true) 
            {return i;} 
        else{return false;}
    }
}

var predicate = function (first) {
    return first % 2 == 0;
}

console.log(findIt(arr, predicate));

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 5];
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `i.length`, but `i` is not the list.

You should return that no match was found after the loop when you know that none of the items match, not when the first match fails.

To match what the `_find` method does, it should return the item, not the index of the item, and return `undefined` if there is no match.

You are using the variable `arr` before assigning the value to it.

```
var findIt = function(list, predicate) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (predicate(list[i]) == true) {
        return list[i];
      }
    }
    return undefined;
}

var predicate = function (first) {
    return first % 2 == 0;
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 5];

console.log(findIt(arr, predicate));
```

Answer (score 2):

List of problems in your code

1. You are assigning value to `arr`, only after passing it to `findIt` function. So, it will have the default value `undefined` in it.
2. In the for loop, if the first element doesn't match the expected element, then you are immediately returning `false`, but you should be checking all the elements before returning `false`.
3. The loop must be run on the length of the `list`, but you are using `i.length`, which will not work because `i` is a number and it will not have `length` property.